# Why is MYSQL time behind server time by 2 minutes

Tags: mysql, timestamp

When I did

```
sudo hwclock --show
```

I get

```
Mon 12 Aug 2019 08:37:07 PM EDT
```

Then when I did

```
SELECT NOW();
```

I get

```
 2019-08-12 20:35:15
```

Why is my MYSQL behind my server time, and more importantly how do I get them back in sync!?? I thought they used the same clocks?

Its screwing up some of my auto-execute features in my software.

Comment: What does the `date` command show

Comment: @Barmar it also shows 3 minutes behind.  So then, why is my server behind the rest of the world by 3 minutes?

Comment: In the shell. Is it the same as `hwclock --show`? The hardware clock is not the same as the system time.

Comment: MySQL uses the system clock, not the hardware clock, just like everything else.

Comment: So how do I get my system clock in sync with the hardware clock/rest of the world?

Comment: Read the notes in the man page here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock

Comment: If you're running NTP, the system clock is usually more accurate than the hardware clock, since it synchronizes with official time sources.

Comment: From the man page: **The Hardware Clock is usually not very accurate.**

Comment: ok, I just did sudo hwclock -s to sync up the system with hardware.